# How to create a list of all folder in a shared drive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a shared drive file in google drive that I need to extract a list of all the folder names to google sheets (just at the first level at this stage). I can't seem to get the code to work, I've tried all different types - I think it's because it's a shared drive and not a folder as such.

Note I don't want a list of files, just the folder names under that shared drive.

This was the latest code I was working on but it just comes up blank.

```
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldername = 'your-folder';
  var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;
  
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );
  
  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var row;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
  }  
};
```

Comment: In a shared drive I'd probably use Drive API

Comment: Thanks Cooper - can you point me in the right direction - how do I use Drive API - I'm happy to learn I just don't know where to start?

Comment: Hi @RoosterMagic22, you can find there a repo with function, documentation and others link to usefull ressource :  https://github.com/SolannP/UtilsAppSsript .
Be carefull, you have to import Drive API on app script. 
 [drive description](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)
 [api ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference)

Comment: THanks @PuygrenierS. - I will keep researching, I've got your links saved so I can review them and go over them. Questions - can you enable Goggle Drive API and then write a script as normal or is Drive API a separate application?

Comment: @RoosterMagic22, First one is correct, write a script and enable GDrive API (+ button at the right)